# High CPU Usage using USB-C Monitor with Ubuntu 21.10 and ASUS ROG G14

Tags: nvidia, 21.10, external-monitor, amdgpu, usb-c

I'm using Ubuntu 21.10 all updated as of today. Ive got an AMD ROG G14, it have NVIDIA and AMD GPU

My cpu is jumping like crazy when I connect my micro USB monitor

```
16122 yoram     20   0   25.8g 163468  96268 S  42.2   0.5   1:41.32 Xorg                                                                                                                                        
16349 yoram     20   0 5225836 309364 128988 S  13.3   1.0   0:33.23 gnome-shell
```

If I disconnect the USB-C it goes back no normal

When I do

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Trying to select the on-demand PRIME profile
Info: selecting the on-demand profile
Writing /lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-runtimepm.conf
Updating the initramfs. Please wait for the operation to complete:
|W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/vangogh_gpu_info.bin for module amdgpu
-W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_ta.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_sos.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_rlc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_mec2.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_mec.bin for module amdgpu
|W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_sdma.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_vcn.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/aldebaran_smc.bin for module amdgpu
```

I'm not sure if it is related.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Unrelated. Try selecting the Nvidia GPU instead of "on demand" and test how it goes.

Comment: Hi, I tested and it didn't work. But I found that if I change the primary monitor to the HDMI one, the problem go away. Any idea why?